# Laravel and JQuery URL call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, url-routing

I'm trying to delete a picture from a profile site. Upload ist working but if I want to delete the ajax call is not working correctly. I'm a laravel beginner and just playing around.

My Head Form is this:

```
    {{ $profileImageSection }}
<form
    name="update-account"
    action="{{ route('customer.account.profile.action') }}"
    accept-charset="UTF-8"
    enctype="multipart/form-data"
    class="with-padding with-validation"
    data-image-action="{{ route('customer.account.profile.image.action') }}"
    data-image-delete="{{ route('customer.account.profile.image.delete') }}">
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
    <input type="hidden" name="account_type" value="_Private" />
    <div class="holder message"></div>
```

My ProfileImageSection is this:

```
    <section class="profile-image">
<div class="profileimage-round">
    @if (empty($image))
    <figure class="placeholder"><i></i></figure>
    @else
    <figure class="placeholder" style="background: url({{ $image }}) no-repeat"></figure>
    @endif
</div>
<form class="upload" name="upload-profile-image">
    <label>Drope here</label>
    <img src="{{ asset('assets/images/loader.gif') }}" />
    <a href="#" class="chose">Choose</a>
    <input type="file" name="profile" class="updatepic" style="/*display: block !important;*/ opacity: 0"/>
</form>
@if (!empty($image))
<form class="delete" name="delete-profile-image">
    <a href="#" class="delete">Delete</a>
    <input type="button" name="profile" class="deletepic" style="/*display: block !important;*/ opacity: 0"/>
</form>
@endif
```

What I tried with javascript is somthing like:

```
$('.profile-image .delete a.delete').click(function()
    {
        $(this).parent().find('.deletepic').click();
    });

    $.('form[name=delete-profile-image]')({
        url: $('form[name=update-account]').data('image-delete'),
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json'
    });
```

the URL is correctly and I'm routing like:

```
    Route::post('/delete', array(
            'as'    => 'customer.account.profile.image.delete',
            'uses'  => 'UserProfileController@postImage'
        ));
```

But it's not working. I tried a lot and can't find a solution anymore. I think the routing is not calling. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: No, just nothing happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of issues I see..

If you use the [form helpers](http://laravel.com/docs/html) ( `Form::open()` / `Form::close()` ) you won't need to include the hidden CSRF token element manually.  However the bigger issue is your javascript:

```
$('.profile-image .delete a.delete').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().find('.deletepic').click();
});

$.('form[name=delete-profile-image]')({
    url: $('form[name=update-account]').data('image-delete'),
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json'
});
```

Where is the AJAX call? (Hint, it's just not there..)  Why would you have an anchor element trigger a click on a hidden button inside a form when you can just fire off the AJAX call on the anchor itself?  Try changing your HTML to something like this...

```
@if (!empty($image))
    <a href="#" class="delete">Delete</a>
    {{ Form::open(array('url' => route('customer.account.profile.image.delete'), 'style' => 'display: none', 'id' => 'image_delete')) }}
        {{ Form::text('image', $image) }}
    {{ Form::close() }}
@endif
```

And update your javascript to something like this:

```
$('.profile-image .delete a.delete').click(function() {
    $('#image_delete').submit()
});
```

Comment: Oh, I see, of course you are right! Thank you for that quick reply. Now it is routing to /delete.
I just wanna call UserProfileController@postImage with ajax under /delete. So that the user don't leave the current site. Like the image upload with "Dropzone". 'action' => 'UserProfileController@postImage' didn't work.
Now how I call it but don't leave the Site?